# Two-variable limit problem: the limit of $(\cos^2(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})-1)/(x^2+y^2)$ as $(x,y)\to 0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

What is the value of $k$ such that $f$ is continuos in $(0,0)$?
$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac {\cos^2\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)-1}{x^2+y^2},  & \text{if $(x,y)$ $\ne$ (0,0)} \\[2ex]
k, & \text{if $(x,y)$ = (0,0)}
\end{cases}$$

I'm stuck. I need to solve this with algebraic manipulation. Maybe transforming it in a fundamental limit: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$$ or $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos(x)-1}{x}=0$$

Comment: Use the taylor expansion of $\cos$.

Comment: I need to solve this without Taylor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: try polar coordinates, i.e.
$$f(r):=(\cos^2 r-1)/r^2\ if \ r\neq 0,\ f(0)=k...$$ 
and solve
$$\lim_{r\to 0}f(r)=k.$$

Or note
$$\cos^2(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})-1=-\sin^2(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$$
and
$$\lim_{x^2+y^2\to 0}\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})}{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=1.$$
Note also that letting $x^2+y^2\to 0$ is equivalent to letting $x,y\to 0$.

Comment: I didn't learn polar coordinates yet. I'm suppose to solve it only with algebraic manipulation.

Comment: Polar coordinates is just a name, the underlying manipulation is substitution $r:=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: Substitution is also just a name. I believe the OP is saying he didn't learn about this technique yet.

Comment: Based on what i'v learned, I need to turn this into a fundamental limit like $sin(x)/x$ and $(cos(x)-1)/x$

Comment: To get polar: let $x=r \sin(\theta)$ and $y=r \cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Ok, I see OP's point. Answer edited.

Comment: Yes! I guess that is what I should get. Just a quick fix for anyone that might be helped by this question, I think the final answer is -1 instead of 1.

Comment: Oh the problem is that there is no root on the denominator. :/

Comment: If you want yes: $x^2+y^2=(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2$ (and there is square of $\sin$ at numerator too)